# Mac run shell script startup

Tags: shell, plist

I have a plist file that should start a shell script on startup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.app.localclient</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>~/Documents/Local_client/Server.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've saved the plist file as `com.app.localclient.plist` and have tested the shell script which works fine. When I try to load the script with `launchctl load com.app.localclient.plist`, it loads the plist but does not start the shell script. I've also changed the Program parameter `~` to `/Users/username/`, but with no succes. Is there a way to make the plist start the shell script and can this be done without knowing the username of where the script is saved (so by using ~ in the path).

Comment: Have you tried `$HOME` in place of `~`? Also, where are you storing this file?

Comment: I just tried $HOME and that gives the following error: Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments. I saved the .plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try running a shell as that will know your $HOME:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>"$HOME/Documents/Local_client/Server.sh"</string>
</array>
```

In order to debug this, please try:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>"echo hi > /tmp/DEBUG.txt"</string>
</array>
```

and see if `/tmp/DEBUG.txt` exists afterwards. If that works, try making the last string

```
"/usr/bin/whoami > /tmp/DEBUG.txt"
```

and then see what is in `/tmp/DEBUG.txt`

Comment: I don't get any errors anymore and the plist file is loaded, but the shell script is unfortunately still not running.

Comment: Try making the permissions very generous for testing - you can always close them down later. Also, try running a simple `echo "Hi I ran" > /tmp/a` as a first attempt, then try `echo "Hi I ran" > /Users/YOU/Desktop/yes.txt`

Comment: So I tried the first simple example. Again the plist file loads with no errors, but the script is not executed. If I just run the script then it executes fine and prints "Hi I ran" in the terminal. I've put the script in root, users and home, but none worked.

Comment: Maybe try full path to `bash` as `/bin/bash`.

Comment: That gives the same problem.

Comment: I tried that, but the file does not exists afterwards.